# Need help understanding pointer variable assignments

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm not good at advanced C++ scripts. I have tried to find out more about the following variable assignments without success. Please explain them or give me a source to study similar statements.

```
rand_seed = *(int*)input_buffer_ptr;
moving_input_ptr = (BYTE*)((int*)input_buffer_ptr + 1);
```

Comment: The first expression is quite simple: extract the first item of `input_buffer_ptr` pointer after `int *` cast. The `rand_seed` shall be an 'int`.

Answer (score 2):

(Considering that `int` is 4 bytes)

Imagine RAM as a long line of bytes (because it is):

```
RAM: .... [8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit] ....
```

and `SOME_TYPE*` as the pointer on some byte:

```
.... [8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit] ....
           ^
      input_buffer_ptr
```

`int*` means that you treat data under this pointer as integer (number of size 4 bytes)

So if you have pointer `SOME_TYPE* input_buffer_ptr`

```
(int*)input_buffer_ptr; // casts this pointer to int*, 
     //so now you treat data under this pointer as 4 bytes integer
```

then:

```
*(int*)input_buffer_ptr; // operator * before pointer gets data under 
          //that pointer, in this case, integer (4 bytes).
```

So `rand_seed` is integer and has value:

```
.... [8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit] ....
           |      random_seed     |
```

Then:

```
     (int*)input_buffer_ptr + 1
//    ^                     ^
// casting to int*      moving pointer to size of int (4 bytes)
```

So:

```
.... [8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit] ....
                                   ^
                         ((int*)input_buffer_ptr + 1)
```

And then:

```
 (BYTE*)((int*)input_buffer_ptr + 1);
// ^
// casting pointer to BYTE*, so it points to the same place
// but now treated as one byte pointer.
```

so if you try this:

```
BYTE a = *(BYTE*)((int*)input_buffer_ptr + 1);
```

you will get one byte variable with value:

```
.... [8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit][8bit] ....
                                   |  a  |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great detailed answer @Yevhen Kuzmovych.

Comment: Note: this is undefined behaviour (strict aliasing violation) unless the buffer was originally written via `int` also.